# SwiftUI @Environment(\.refresh) no longer works with iOS 17.1

Tags: ios, swiftui

Following Apple's documentation for refresh I can get the refreshable modifier to work on iOS 16.4 and iOS 17.0.1, but it stops working on iOS 17.1 and continues to not work in 17.2 beta 3.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/refresh

Simple code. The application will hang on iOS 17.1+ but work fine on 17.0.1.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RefreshableView()
            .refreshable {
                print("Refresh finished!")
            }
    }
}

struct RefreshableView: View {
    @Environment(\.refresh) private var refresh

    var body: some View {
        Button("Refresh") {
            print("Refresh started")
            Task {
                await refresh?()
            }
        }
        .disabled(refresh == nil)
    }
}
```

Curious if anyone has a similar experience or a workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating `Task{}` like what you have inside the action are not considered good practice. It is better to use a `.task(id:)` and have the button trigger an `id` change.

```
import SwiftUI

struct RefreshableParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RefreshableView()
            .refreshable {
                print("Refresh finished!")
            }
    }
}

struct RefreshableView: View {
    @Environment(\.refresh) private var refresh
    @State private var taskId: UUID?
    var body: some View {
        Button("Refresh") {
            print("Refresh started")
            taskId = .init()
        }
        //Disable the button when the id is set
        .disabled(refresh == nil)
        .task(id: taskId) {
            //Guard against running the task onAppear
            guard taskId != nil  else {
                return
            }
            print("starting")
            await refresh?()
            //Return the id to a nil state
            taskId = nil
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    RefreshableParentView()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The code is from Apple's own documentation on refresh. May I ask why it's not considered to be a good practice to call a task from a button action?

Comment: @KevinMotschmann because there is no lifecycle management. Once you call it, it is left floating and if the view is redrawn it is lost. Once if async/awaits greatest virtues is that you know exactly what is going on and where.

Comment: @KevinMotschmann did the solution work? If so do you mind clicking on the green checkmark?

Comment: Yes, it worked for the scenario presented. It's not working when applied to my project, but I'm still investigating why that is.

Comment: @loremipsum, I disagree with this. There are absolutely times when you are right, but I also find that it is quite often that I want the task to happen whether the view sticks around or not. For example, say that I have a SummaryView for some object, followed by a drill down into a few detail levels with a refresh button on the last page that refreshes the object. Hitting refresh and then backing up a level shouldn't cancel the object refresh. It really depends upon the situation.

Comment: @JasonBobier I get what you are saying but this is one of many examples where the floating Task causes issues, if you search around you’ll find a ton of issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a deadlock introduced in SwiftUI between their async update thread and the main thread (from what I can tell). I've tried several workarounds including the .task(id:) above and shunting to the main thread and back. Nothing works consistently in all cases (the worst possible situation... sometimes the workaround works... ugh...). I've sent in a bug report with a minimal example: FB13659977.